# Express how to avoid this --> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: express

I have this endpoint that keeps failing with the error in the title.

```
router.post(
  "/endpoint/:id/dostuff",
  async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    await Promise.all([
      ...
      body("status").exists().isNumeric().run(req),
      ...
    ]);
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    const now = moment.utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    const {
      publication_id,
      ...
    } = req.body;

  //2. POST to ENDPOINT  /calendar

    try {
      const mapCalendarBodyToPayload = {data: "some_random_data"}

      const calendarPayload: CalendarPayload = issues.map(
        mapCalendarBodyToPayload
      );

      const calendarResponse = await postCalendar(calendarPayload);
      console.log(calendarResponse)  //THIS RETURNS A 200
      
      console.log("TEST6") //gets there

      res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(calendarResponse);


    } catch (err) {
   //It gets there --> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
      res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({
        error: err,
        status: true,
      });
    }
  }
)
```

FOr some reason despite being able to read the calendarResponse , it ends up in the catch and throws a maximum call stack excepcion

Answer (score 0):

My calendarResponse was way too big to be processed by JSON